How to set Active and Selected Object into another Scene?
Let's start from the idea that setting Active Object and selected objects, within the current scene is possible through:
ob_1 = C.scene.objects['ob_1']
ob_2 = C.scene.objects['ob_2']
ob_3 = C.scene.objects['ob_3']

active_object = C.scene.objects['Active']
my_object_list = [ob_1, ob_2, ob_3]

for o in my_object_list :
    o.select_set(state=True)


context.view_layer.objects.active = active_object

Now, let's say we want to set the same objects that are also in a scene that is not the context one,
for example they are in "Scene 2", how can I do this without having to necessarily pass "Scene 2" as the active scene?

Just like with the context example, you have to set the active object via the view_layer attribute of the scene. Pretty straightforward.
import bpy
from bpy import data as D
from bpy import context as C

# Mannequin_01 & 02 exist in one scene, Monkey_01 & 02 in the other
# both scenes 02 is the active & selected object

set_obj1 = D.objects['Mannequin_01']
set_obj2 = D.objects['Monkey_01']

scene_01 = D.scenes['Scene']
scene_02 = D.scenes['Scene.001']

vls_01 = scene_01.view_layers
vls_02 = scene_02.view_layers    


for layer in vls_01:
    layer.objects.active =  set_obj1     
    
for layer in vls_02:
    layer.objects.active =  set_obj2

